# How to configure new BitBucket webhook for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, hook

Since BitBucket 5.4 it's not necessary anymore to install some plugin to enable webhooks to jenkins (push to bitbucket -> trigger jenkins build).

I'm now trying to configure this on our BitBucket 5.9.1.
I've clicked create webhook on my repo:

```
Name: test-webhook
URL: https://ourjenkins/
secret: MyToken
```

In my jenkins job I've configured: `Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)` and also added the same token: `MyToken`.

When I test the setup I got a 403:

```
Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

What am I missing to authenticate? I hoped the token would be used to authenticate but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Jenkins --> Manage Jenkins --> Configure Global Security

Select **Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy** under **Authorization**

Set permission for Anonymous User to Read / Write Jenkins Jobs. Check for overall Read should work in your case. You can also try other options.

Comment: We are using a role based strategy so I don't think I can make it matrix based? :/

Comment: Admin can manage / assign roles. Option available under Manage Jenkins setting.

Comment: Yes, Please go to Manage Jenkins --> Manage and Assign Roles --> Assign Roles. Select checkbox for anonymous for Global roles.This usually considered as unsafe though.

Comment: Good to hear! =)

Comment: Why is it considered as unsafe? I have created a role Anonymous (only read) and assign the role to the anonymous user

Comment: Anyone accessing Jobs can trigger it which you may not like.

Comment: You can create some group like developers and add your account into it. Don't forget to give permissions to developer group.

Comment: Yes there exist some grouping system. anonymous user is the only one in the Anonymous group. Do I need some additional jenkins configuration in the job? I get a 200 but the job is not triggered after a commit (I tried with and without the token)

Comment: What you are doing looks fine.  Job not getting triggered may be different issue then. What does error say?

Comment: I don't see any error. The job is just doing anything. Do I have to define the jenkins URL or the URL to the job in my webhook configuration? The only thing I'm doing in the job is cloning the repo using the git plugin

Comment: With bitbucket, you get an option 'Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket'

Comment: While using 'GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling', don't forget to add Jenkins Job URL to githooks in git repo settings

Comment: Use any of the one above mentioned options which suits your need.